# git rebase failing due to whitespace error

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to rebase a branch and git is pooping out because it's attempting to perform some merge action which fails. How do I get git to stop this?

```
# git rebase -f --onto master~2 master~ master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: r1002 - CS 1.0.23
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   about.html
<stdin>:68: trailing whitespace.                     
<stdin>:115: trailing whitespace.
<stdin>:201: trailing whitespace.
<stdin>:2369: trailing whitespace.
<stdin>:2385: trailing whitespace.
warning: squelched 2305 whitespace errors
warning: 2310 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging about.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in about.html
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 r1002 - 1002
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   /local/melder/tmp/test/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

As you can see there are 2000+ whitespace errors, not something easy to merge by hand.

<strike>Edit: to side step this for now without merging I did:</strike>

```
# git add -A
# git rebase --continue
```

Edit: nevermind that is a silly idea.

Answer (score 26):

I faced the same problem today: rebase fails due to conflicts caused by whitespace errors.
After failed trials with different settings for the `whitespace` option (`git rebase --whitespace=fix` and `git rebase --whitespace=nowarn`), the solution that worked for me was to ignore trailing whitespace errors in the recursive merging strategy (`git rebase --abort` any running rebase first if needed):

```
git rebase -Xignore-space-at-eol <newbase>
```

Depenending on the kind of whitespace errors, options `-Xignore-space-change` and `-Xignore-all-space` might be more useful. I don't know if the option `--ignore-whitespace` would have also worked.

Comment: `--ignore-whitespace` did not work for me - it returned exactly the same as without it.
but the `-Xignore`... paramaters didn't work either - they left me with the same merge conflicts, but without the message that there was a whitespace problem.

Comment: @andrewlorien Are you sure that those conflicts are caused by white space errors, or are they real code conflicts? My comment just applies to the first case.

Comment: Good question, thanks.  I've fixed the errors manually now, but i suspect there were a mixture of whitespace and real errors.  I think --ignore-whitespace didn't help, but i think -Xignore-space-at-eol did actually ignore the whitespace problems, leaving me to fix the other problems which were on the same line.

Answer (score 5):

that will not side step the issue. You now have conflict markers in your file!

The whitespace issue are warnings and you should not have as many legitimate conflicts. If the file is a nightmare to resolve, you may need to reconstruct it by hand. This depends on what you're doing though.

Many times the two bases are so different that each commit you are rebasing make you deal with this monstrous conflict. I tend to steer clear of rebase workflows and subscribe to merge/reset. Here's what I do: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

If your issues are only whitespace problems like line endings, you can try and clean up your repository by doing a filter branch or an interactive rebase on each side first to get whitespace on each commit to be consistent.

Also I use beyond compare 3 or Perforce Merge to do conflict resolutions. BC3 is syntax aware and should deal with whitespace the best. A lot of times, it won't even open up as it will resolve the conflicts for you and you can just continue.

Comment: Hmm... you're right, that's no good. I tried using the rebase -X theirs strategy and that worked. The thing is I'm trying to automate this rebasing process. There should be no real conflicts in the repo, I believe the whitespace errors are caused by unix/windows movements. I would like to sidestep that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Today I solved such a problem this way:

```
REMOVE_AFTER="3cd7a0db76ff9dca48979e24c39b408c"
REPO="git@github.com:company/repo.git"
cd ~/tmp
git clone $REPO gitfix
cd gitfix
git checkout --orphan temp $REMOVE_AFTER
git commit -m "Truncated history"
git rebase --strategy=recursive --strategy-option=theirs --onto temp $REMOVE_AFTER master
```

When during the rebase you get a `CONFLICT (modify/delete)` conflict which is caused by a deleted file, you can solve it this way:

```
git rm path/to/both/deleted/file
git rebase --continue
```

When during the rebase you get an other conflict, you will need to manually fix it, and afterwards:

```
git add path/to/conflict/file
git rebase --continue
```

When you are finished, the rebase says `All done.` Then you can:

```
git branch -D temp
```

Now check the result:

```
git log --format=oneline
```

Comment: To which branch/change does REMOVE_AFTER refer?

Comment: @EdRandall don't exactly remember. I guess my fix was made to solve a conflict because of a removed file. So I guess REMOVE_AFTER is the git commit after which the conflicting commits happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think most diff viewers (specially those with a GUI) let you select how to handle whitespace changes.

I'd suggest you to use something like `meld` as your `git mergetool` to auto-correct those conflicts. When `meld` is launched, set it's whitespace-handling policy (from the `Text filters` tab of `Preferences` panel), and it will auto-adjust those changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I would like to automate this process. I'm handling very large repos that have whitespace issues because of developers working on different systems and moving the code over a variety of OSes. It is not practical for me to go in there and merge every single repo when we have hundreds and within them thousands of whitespace inconsistencies.